# Why doesn't my .desktop file work?

Tags: gnome, .desktop

I've downloaded postman and I want to be able to start it from the Gnome search functionality (like I open all my applications). So following [this guide](https://medium.com/@amarprabhu/create-a-shortcut-in-ubuntu-for-postman-native-app-f9864c17faa6) I created a `.desktop` file on the following location: `/home/kramer65/.local/share/applications/.desktop` which contains this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=Postman
Comment=Postman Native App
Exec=/home/kramer65/bin/Postman-linux-x64-6.0.10/Postman/Postman — %u
Icon=/home/kramer65/bin/Postman-linux-x64-6.0.10/Postman/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=postman
Type=Application
Categories=Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/tg;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

When I hit the super key and search for postman in the search bar however, I can't find it.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Where did you place the `.desktop` file? In `/home/kramer65/.local/share/applications/` folder or `/home/kramer65/.local/share/applications/.desktop/` folder?

Comment: What is `Postman — %u` for in your `Exec=` line? Is it literally like that in your .desktop file? And why the need for the `.desktop` subfolder in `/home/kramer65/.local/share/applications/.desktop/`

Comment: By the way, did you try the .desktop file shown in https://blog.bluematador.com/posts/postman-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-1604/ assuming that it's the same postman?

Comment: Did you name the new desktop file, i.e `name.desktop` where name could be anything you want, single word is best or no spaces. Or did you make it `.desktop`. If the later then delete `.desktop` & do again . Also at the end of the Exec= line it's a `--` not a `—`   After adding a new proper desktop file to an applications folder a log out/in may be needed for it to show.

Comment: @doug - Turns out I had to rename the file to `postman.desktop` for it to work. If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case the website wasn't exactly clear that one needed to create a named desktop file which lead the Op to creating a file named `.desktop`

This wouldn't be considered a valid desktop file, more like a hidden file named desktop.

The solution was to rename the .desktop file to `postman.desktop`

Also to remember many websites turn `--` into `—`which is useless in an Exec= line.